# How to make twilio work with a proxy in java

Tags: java, proxy, twilio

Our application is java based web application.
We cannot access third party api directly in this case https://api.twilio.com
This has to be done through a proxy.
Can anyone tell me how can I achieve it for TwilioRestClient?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.getHttpClient()` method of `TwilioRestClient` and set your proxy parameters like this:

```
final TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
client.getHttpClient().getHostConfiguration().setProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late for you, but I've been working around it because setting connection parameters directly to Apache's HttpClient is now deprecated. It is all done through builders and factories now. This is how I've done it with Apache httpcomponents 4.3.4:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, "http");
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
    );    
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .build();
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
client.setHttpclient(httpClient);

//do your regular stuff with this client
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using above 7.0.0 or latest jar Twilio has provided its own HttpClient, follow these steps,

1) You need to create your customHttpProxy class that extends com.twilio.http.HttpClient

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultProxyRoutePlanner;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.exception.ApiException;
import com.twilio.http.HttpClient;
import com.twilio.http.HttpMethod;
import com.twilio.http.Request;
import com.twilio.http.Response;

import XXXX.XXX.twilio.util.TwilioUtil;

public class CustomNetworkClient extends HttpClient {

    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private static final int CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE = 10;

    private org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client;

    private String twilioRequestId;

    private Float twilioResponseDuration;


    /**
     * Create a new HTTP Client.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public CustomNetworkClient() throws Exception {
        this.invokeHttpProxy();
    }

    /**
     * Make a request.
     *
     * @param request request to make
     * @return Response of the HTTP request
     */
    public Response makeRequest(final Request request) {
        twilioResponseDuration = null;
        twilioRequestId = null;

        RequestBuilder builder = RequestBuilder.create(request.getMethod().toString())
            .setUri(request.constructURL().toString())
            .setVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
            .setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        if (request.requiresAuthentication()) {
            builder.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, request.getAuthString());
        }

        HttpMethod method = request.getMethod();
        if (method == HttpMethod.POST) {
            builder.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : request.getPostParams().entrySet()) {
                for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                    builder.addParameter(entry.getKey(), value);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(builder.build());

            if (response.containsHeader("Twilio-Request-Id"))
                twilioRequestId = response.getFirstHeader("Twilio-Request-Id").getValue();

            if (response.containsHeader("Twilio-Request-Duration"))
                twilioResponseDuration = new Float(response.getFirstHeader("Twilio-Request-Duration").getValue());

            return new Response(
                response.getEntity() == null ? null : response.getEntity().getContent(),
                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
            );            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ApiException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String getTwilioRequestId() {
        return twilioRequestId;
    }

    public Float getTwilioResponseDuration() {
        return twilioResponseDuration;
    }


    public  void invokeHttpProxy()throws Exception {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("YOUR_PROXY_HOST", YOUR_PROXY_PORT, "http");
        DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);

        //Set up Twilio user credentials
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("api.twilio.com", 443), 
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(TwilioUtil.ACCOUNT_SID, TwilioUtil.AUTH_TOKEN));

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
            .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
            .build();

            Collection<Header> headers = Lists.<Header>newArrayList(
                new BasicHeader("X-Twilio-Client", "java-" + Twilio.VERSION),
                new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "twilio-java/" + Twilio.VERSION + " (" + Twilio.JAVA_VERSION + ")"),
                new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json"),
                new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "utf-8")
            );


        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                 .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider) 
            .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
           .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE)
            .build();
    }
}
```

2) Inject the custom class into Twilio and TwilioRestClient respectively.

```
 CustomNetworkClient newHttpClient = new CustomNetworkClient();
 Twilio.init(TwilioUtil.ACCOUNT_SID, TwilioUtil.AUTH_TOKEN);
 TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(TwilioUtil.ACCOUNT_SID, TwilioUtil.AUTH_TOKEN).httpClient(newHttpClient)
                .build();`enter code here`
                Twilio.setRestClient(client);
```

Hope this is helpful to your guys.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the preceding. I write a much elegant class than ustomNetworkClient

```
import com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

public class ProxyAuthenticateHttpClient extends NetworkHttpClient {

    private ProxyAuthenticateHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder) {
        super(clientBuilder);
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class Builder {
        public ProxyAuthenticateHttpClient build() {
            HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
            clientBuilder.useSystemProperties();

            RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
                .build();

            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword));

            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
            connectionManager.setMaxTotal(10*2);

            clientBuilder
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config);

            return new ProxyAuthenticateHttpClient(clientBuilder);
        }

        private final String proxyHost;
        private final int proxyPort;
        private final String proxyUser;
        private final String proxyPassword;

        private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30500;
    }
}
```

Then use the following code to init Twilio and everything is OK

```
Twilio.init(username, password);
TwilioRestClient.Builder builder = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(username, password);
builder.httpClient(new ProxyAuthenticateHttpClient.Builder(proxyUser, proxyPort, proxyUser, proxyPassword).build());
Twilio.setRestClient(builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ful Source code = https://github.com/mjg123/Twilio-custom-http-clients/blob/main/src/main/java/com/twilio/helperv8/RestClientProxy.java

Twilio's api lives on the internet, and many folks on corporate networks will therefore need to configure an http proxy to access it. Again this is possible with a custom twiliorestclient, although in this case we'll need to write some code of our own. There are a few layers to this, so let's unpack them:
a twiliorestclient builder can take a custom instance of com. Twilio. Http. Httpclient. (this would be a good place to inject a mock for testing your calls to the twilio api)
the default implementation of twilio's httpclient is called networkhttpclient.
Networkhttpclient can be initialised with an apache httpcomponents httpclientbuilder.
Httpclientbuilder can be configured to use a proxy.

To create an httpclient instance, this code is sufficient:

private static HttpClient createProxiedHttpClient(String proxyHost, int proxyPort) {

```
// you can also configure things like caching, custom HTTPS certs,
// timeouts and connection pool sizes here.
// See: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html
HttpClientBuilder apacheClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));

return new NetworkHttpClient(apacheClientBuilder);
```

}

private static final String PROXY_HOST = "localhost";
private static final int PROXY_PORT = 8888;

public static void main(String[] args) {

HttpClient proxiedHttpClient = createProxiedHttpClient(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

```
TwilioRestClient proxiedTwilioClient = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(
        PROJECT_CAKE_ACCOUNT_SID,
        PROJECT_CAKE_AUTH_TOKEN)
    .httpClient(proxiedHttpClient)
    .build();

Message.creator(
        TO_PHONE_NUMBER,
        PROJECT_CAKE_PHONE_NUMBER,
        "Cake, or Pie?")
    .create(proxiedTwilioClient);
```

}