# Sending sms using Twilio API-java from proxy

Tags: java, proxy, twilio

I am trying to use Twilio-7 api to send sms. I am on proxy network.I am getting following error.

Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: 8 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: api.twilio.com port: 443
   at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:128)

i am using following code :

```
//Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultProxyRoutePlanner;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

import com.twilio.sdk.*;


    public class TwilioRestTest {
     // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
     public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "SID";
     public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "PWD";
     public static final String PROXY_ADDRESS = "proxy-address.com";
     public static final int PROXY_PORT = 80;
     private static final String PROXY_PASSWORD = null;
     private static final String PROXY_USER = null;
     /**
     * @param args
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",PROXY_ADDRESS );
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT);
         Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

         Message message = Message
                 .creator(new PhoneNumber("+1112323223"),  // to
                          new PhoneNumber("+15005550006"),  // from
                          "Where's Wallace?")
                 .create();
         System.out.println("Test:"+message.getStatus());
     }
    }
```

i tried approach describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378429/twilio-java-connection-with-proxy-authentication) but then i am getting compilation error as

> TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID,
>   AUTH_TOKEN); 
>           client.setHttpClient(httpClient); No constructor of type TwilioRestClient(string, String) found No symbol found setHttpClient
>   of type TwilioRestClient.

Any lead would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
[Link](http://blog.nbostech.com/2016/11/make-twilio-api-calls-through-proxy-server/)

Main method :

```
Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN).httpClient(new ProxyNetworkHttpClient()).build();
Twilio.setRestClient(client);
Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("TO"),new PhoneNumber("FROM"), "MESSAGE").create();
```