# Is there a way to configure TwilioRestClient with custom URL

Tags: java, twilio

I am doing a small POC to use TwilioRestClient with custom URL. I have gone through few post to configure TwilioRestClient with proxy server I don’t want to use proxy server. Since I am aware of Twilio URL so I want to use the custom URL to send the SMS. Any suggestions much appreciated.
Please find the below code

```
String host = “verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/“
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(host,-1,”https”);
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy);
this.httpClient = new NetworkHttpClient(clientBuilder);
TwilioRestClient.Builder builder = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(account_sid,account_auth_token);
builder.httpClient(this.httpClient).build();
```

The problem is Twilio uses below verify api

```
“https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/service_sid/Verifications”
```

My question is how could I get Service_sid information or can I directly invoke `https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/`

Comment: Can you post some code of what you are trying to do? You can create a custom URL that you host and then use Twilio to send the SMS. Your custom URL will use the Twilio REST API to send the SMS.

Comment: I have added code snippets for your reference could you check once thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided it seems that you are trying to use verify.twilio.com as a proxy server. The [verify.twilio.com](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify) is an end-point for a Twilio service to verify end-users which is not needed to send SMS.

If you are trying to create a custom TwilioRestClient, here is a code sample from  the Twilio #C SDK for a custom [TwilioRestClient](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/main/advanced-examples/custom-http-client.md):

```
public static class ProxiedTwilioClientCreator
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient;

        private static void CreateHttpClient()
        {
            var proxyUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyServerUrl"];
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl),
                UseProxy = true
            };

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            var byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUsername"]
                    + ":"
                    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyPassword"]
            );

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)
                );
        }

        public static TwilioRestClient GetClient()
        {
            var accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSid"];
            var authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];

            if (_httpClient == null)
            {                    
                CreateHttpClient();
            }

            var twilioRestClient = new TwilioRestClient(
                accountSid,
                authToken,
                httpClient: new Twilio.Http.SystemNetHttpClient(_httpClient)
            );

            return twilioRestClient;
        }
    }
```

The proxy server will make it appear to your client applications that you are sending from a different non-Twilio url. However, if you are using a server based app such as ASP.NET or Blazor Server then your client application won't have access to the url so no real need to do this. Twilio explains this further in a blob post on ["Protect Your Identify with Proxy Servers, Twilio, and C#"](https://www.twilio.com/blog/protect-your-identity-with-proxy-servers-twilio-and-c-html).

Comment: Hi Jassent do you have Java code for this. What wrong with my code? Why it is not working.

Comment: TeamZ, I do not have code for Java but Stack Overflow has this from 2014: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230722/how-to-make-twilio-work-with-a-proxy-in-java

Comment: Your solution partially helped me to write the poc. Thank you.